# Remember selected option after redirect

Tags: php, javascript, datatables

Basicly, I have a `<select>` with a few options, when selected, it loads a `jQuery dataTables` table with content, in that table are options to edit/delete that content.

When a user deletes this content, or edits, it's redirected back to the first page, having to select the category again.

How would I set it so, that the `<select>` is auto selected, and the dataTable also loaded after an redirect?

My project is in PHP, so I can track what category it 'came from'

Comment: Make a `$_SESSION` variable for it, and make it add selected in the select or echo it to a javascript variable

Comment: show some code,what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

To auto select the category from your categories:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#categories").val('<?php echo $selected_category;?>');
});
```

Assuming you have the `$selected_category` value (what category it came from).